# Set value to java class by reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have this model :

```
public class Base_RegisterPlack {


    private String RegisterPlackTypeValue;

    public void setRegisterPlackTypeValue(String registerPlackTypeValue) {
        RegisterPlackTypeValue = registerPlackTypeValue;
    }
}
```

in this method i pass this object:

```
gridView2.setAdapter(GridHelper.getRegisterPlackAdapter(getContext(), getCookie(),
        result_getClsBase_Info.getBase_RegisterPlack()), Base_RegisterPlack.class);
```

body of `setAdapter` method is:

```
public void setAdapter (DataGridAdapter adapter, Class cls) {
    this.baseClass = cls;
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
    setGridAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Now i want to call set method `setRegisterPlackTypeValue` so i write this reflection :

```
try {
    Field field = baseClass.getDeclaredField("RegisterPlackTypeValue");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(baseClass,"test");
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I got this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type com.module.contracts.Base_RegisterPlack, but got java.lang.Class<com.module.contracts.Base_RegisterPlack>
```

How can i call set method and convert again this `baseClass` to the `Base_RegisterPlack` after set value to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an instance of the class that `baseClass` represents. How to do this exactly will depend on the design of the actual `baseClass` (i.e., whether it has constructors or static factory methods), and what arguments these needs. In the simplest case, your base class will have a parameterless constructor, and you can simply do:

```
field.set(baseClass.newInstance(),"test");
```

However, you will probably want to retain a reference to whatever instance is returned by `newInstance`.

It's important to remember that with reflection an instance of type `Field` represents a *field declaration* in its declaring class, and not an actual field (instance variable) in an object. Thus, the value stored in variable `field` in your code is not related to any instance. This is why when you call `Field.set(target, value)` you have to supply an object of class `baseClass`. The field of that object, which is represented by `field`, will be set to value `"test"`. See [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) for details.

Comment: How could i extract it's object from field? @derefacto